# How to best develop writing and argumentation skills on a philosophy self-study track?

Tags: argumentation, essay

I am about to embark on a journey of Philosophy self-study. I have a curriculum I want to pursue, covering all majour branches of philosophy. I also have a reading list which includes set texts, text books, articles from major journals. I plan to compliment that by listening to podcasts and watching lectures and philosophical talks on relevant topics. Altogether it should provide a solid theoretical foundation.

My key concern is that one of the most important elements studying philosophy is writing essays and argumentation. These practical aspects are critical to understanding the philosophy and actually buidling the knowledge of the subject.

I would appreciate your ideas as well as any relevant experience you can share.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most effective ways to self-learn philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/36953/most-effective-ways-to-self-learn-philosophy)

Comment: it's a good and specific question that i honestly don't know the answer to at all. you could try asking a autodidact for advice

Comment: @DavidGudeman unfortunately the answer you pointed to is more about the curriculum content, which I'm least concerned about.