# What classical books are suitable for a beginner?

Tags: reference-request

What *classical* books (*not* modern ones) are suitable for a *complete* beginner (meaning having no prior knowledge of philosophy) in philosophy?

I am interested in metaphysics, logic, ethics, aesthetics, religion, ontology. I am interested both in Western and Eastern philosophy.

If you recommend more than one book, please list the books in order of difficulty.

Comment: Replies to your previous question list some classical books http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/36953/most-effective-ways-to-self-learn-philosophy Are you interested in some particular field: logic, epistemology, ontology, ethics, aesthetics...? Some particular school of thought: materialism, idealism, realism, empiricism, transcendentalism, rationalism...?

Comment: Here are some very easy introductory resources: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/22098/13808

Answer (score 3):

I would personally recommend five books of foundational philosophy.  All of them are hugely influential, relatively brief, aimed at a general audience, and not hard to read (*if you find a good translation!*).  One is Middle Eastern (from the Bible), one is Asian, one are European, and the last two are ancient Greek.  I have listed them in rough order of difficulty.

- [Ecclesiastes](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ecclesiastes+3)
- Descartes - *[Meditations](https://www.marxists.org/reference/archive/descartes/1639/meditations.htm)*
- Lao Tzu - [Tao Te Ching](http://www.sacred-texts.com/tao/taote.htm)
- Plato - *[The Republic](http://classics.mit.edu/Plato/republic.2.i.html)* and *[The Symposium](http://classics.mit.edu/Plato/symposium.html)*

You might also find it worth reading any one of the innumerable collections of the wisdom of the Sufis and the Zen Buddhists.

*Note: the links above are to older translations freely available on the internet.  In most cases there are more modern and readable translations available, but not for free.*