# How can I start learning about Philosophy of religion?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion

every religion has unique philosophy that may have Common Traits and Common definitions.

What are the deals Philosophy of religion?

What are the resources Philosophy of religion?

How can people start that?

do they need to start research on a particular religion?

Do they need to adapt them with their religion?

Comment: What work have you already done to investigate this question?  Which sources have you read?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and how can I get started in contemporary philosophy?](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/256/where-and-how-can-i-get-started-in-contemporary-philosophy)

Answer (score 1):

Consider starting with Wikipedia's article on the subject: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_religion